# only shooting from one position

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a 2D game as a school project(only beginners code, no fancy stuff).

my character is supposed to shot from it's own position.

It is only able to get the position from the player when constructed and therefor it only shots from the position where the player started.

here is some code that I find relevant:

```
class ShootManager
{
    int shotsShooten = 0;
    List<Shot> shots = new List<Shot>();

    public void FireShot()
    {
        shots.Add(new Shot());
        shotsShooten++;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, KeyboardState KbState)
    {
        if (KbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        { FireShot(); }

        foreach (Shot shot in shots)
        {
            if (shot.Position.X == (float)shot.ISoutOfGame) //if the shot is out of the screen
                shots.Remove(shots[shots.Count - 1]); //Removes the last item

            shot.Position.X--;
        }
    }
}


class Shot
{
    public Vector2 Position;
    public int ISoutOfGame = -50;

    public Shot(Vector2 position)
    {
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get around with having each shot constructed at the players starting position and rather create it where the player currently is?

Comment: One thing I'm not getting; you create the shot as "shots.Add(new Shot());", but on the constructor you have a vector2 parameter?

Comment: yeah I was going to fix that later once I get a vector2 position from the player. That's why

Comment: And by passing the "Player.Position" as parameter, doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: sorry, I saw what I was doing wrong thanks for the help anyways ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple example how can you do that, it's on VB code from head and not tested.

```
Public Class Bullet
    Position as Vector2
    Velocity as Vector2
    Active as boolean = false
End Class

Public Class Bullets
    inherit list(of Bullet)

    // public sub Init(Position, Velocity, Type, Acting, Speed, Size..... )
    public Sub Init(Position, Velocity)
        dim new Bullet as Bullet
        Bullet.Position = Position
        Bullet.Velocity = Velocity
        Bullet.Active = true
        add(Bullet)
    end Sub

    public Sub Update()
        for each b as bullet in me.findall(function(c) c.active)
            b.position += b.velocity
            // if b.position outside screen then b.active = false
            // also on collision set active to false
        next

        me.removeall(function(c) not(c.active))
    end sub

    public Sub Draw()
        for each b as bullet in me.findall(function(c) c.active)
            // draw bullets
        next
    end Sub
End Class
```